Swig: C++ / Python director and Eigen::VectorXd
I have a virtual C++ class that I want to extend in Python.
This class contains a few computational functions that need to be overloaded.
For instance:
class myCppClass
{
public: 
    myCppClass(){}
    virtual Eigen::vectorXd compute_things();   
    void update_class()
   {
      // ... do things 
      toto = compute_things(); 
      // ... do other things
   }

protected: 
    Eigen::vectorXd _toto; 

};

The idea is that users implement their own compute_things method in Python. This method is called inside the update_class method.
To achieve this, I am using SWIG's director feature along with Eigen typemaps developed by this repository.
Here is what my .i file looks like:
%module(package="example", directors="1", allprotected="1", "threads"=1) My_Example

%{
#include <MyCppClass.h>
}

%import <typemaps.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%include <eigen.i>
%import "numpy.i"

%feature("director") myCppClass;

%include <MyCppClass.h>

Then in python :
class myPythonClass(myCppClass):

   def __init__(self): 
       super().__init__()

   def compute_things(self): 
       return np.array([2.0, 1.0])


myclass = myPythonClass()
myclass.upadate_class()

When I run this code, I get the following error:
"TypeError: SWIG director type mismatch in output value of type 'Eigen::VectorXd'"
However, if I call the compute_things method directly, it works without any issue.
Some additional context:

In my complete code, the instance of myPythonClass is disown()-ed, but I cannot share the full implementation here.
If I replace Eigen::VectorXd with more "standard" types such as std::vector<double>, int, or double, everything works fine.
I tried adding debug print statements in all the Eigen typemaps. It seems that the TypeError occurs before the typemaps are triggered, which leaves me unsure of where the issue lies.

Is this a limitation of the SWIG-Eigen integration, or am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you very much!
also posted here: https://github.com/swig/swig/discussions/3080
